# React trigger only one element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am in the process of making a comment system like the one on youtube. In my implementation, when I click on modify, all comments are now inputs but only the value of the selected input will be modified. how to trigger only the element i clicked.

[image]

[image]

as you can see it triggers all the array elements

```
function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <MDBRow>
        {data &&
          data.map((item) => (
            <MDBCol md="7" lg="7" key={item.id} className="mb-4">
              {!open && (
                <>
                  <div className="font-weight-bolder float-left pr-2">
                    {item.name}
                  </div>
                  <div className="float-right pr-2">
                    <button
                      onClick={() => {
                        setOpen(true);
                      }}
                    >
                      Modifier
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </>
              )}
              {open && (
                <UpdateData
                  id={item.id}
                  name={item.name}
                  onAbort={() => setOpen(false)}
                  submit={() => setOpen(false)}
                />
              )}
            </MDBCol>
          ))}
      </MDBRow>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export const UpdateData = ({ name, id, onAbort, submit }) => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      id: id,
      name: name,
    },
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      console.log(values);
      submit();
    },
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      <MDBInput
        value={formik.values.name}
        name="name"
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
      />
      <div className="float-right">
        <span onClick={onAbort} className="text-capitalize grey-text">
          Cancel
        </span>
        <button type="submit">confirm</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

And this is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-cloud-r4itr)
that i have created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To trigger only one element to be clicked you have to pass the index**

```
    function App() {
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
      const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState(undefined);
    
      const onSelectedRow = (index) => {
       setSelectedRow(index);
       setOpen(true);
     }
    
      return (
        <div className="container mt-5">
          <MDBRow>
            {data &&
// here you will get the index
              data.map((item,index) => ( 
                <MDBCol md="7" lg="7" key={item.id} className="mb-4">
                  {!open && (
                    <>
                      <div className="font-weight-bolder float-left pr-2">
                        {item.name}
                      </div>
                      <div className="float-right pr-2">
// Now onClick pass the index of selected row to onSelectedRow

                        <button
                          onClick={() =>onSelectedRow(index)}
                        >
                          Modifier
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </>
                  )}
// here add condition to open selected row
                  { (open === true && selectedRow === index) ? (
                    <UpdateData
                      id={item.id}
                      name={item.name}
                      onAbort={() => setOpen(false)}
                      submit={() => setOpen(false)}
                    />
                  ) : null
                 }
                </MDBCol>
              ))}
          </MDBRow>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Sandbox code https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-wave-k4eih?file=/src/App.js

**If you have any queries comment below!**

Answer (score 0):

instead of having a `false` default value in your hook you should have a unique key for each element. By default, it applies to all elements.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer and take a bit more time to answer.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your answer. and how i will retrieve the key in useState